# generate a name vector MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How would I generate a vector like

```
x1,x2,x3,x4,...,xn
```

the problem is concatenate ','and a 'x' char

```
n=100
A = (1:n);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate the string `'x1,x2'` etc, you can create a mask for [SPRINTF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html) using [REPMAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html) like so:

```
n = 5;

mask = repmat('x%i,',1,n);

out = sprintf(mask,1:n);

out = out(1:end-1)

out =
x1,x2,x3,x4,x5
```

Note that in case you actually want to create a vector containing the strings `'x1','x2'` etc, you'd use [ARRAYFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html) to generate a cell array:

```
out = arrayfun(@(x)sprintf('x%i',x),1:n,'uniformOutput',false)
out = 
    'x1'    'x2'    'x3'    'x4'    'x5'
```

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240780/generate-a-name-vector-matlab/5242204#5242204) for a similar answer that avoids the mask.

Answer (score 5):

This is a slight improvement on [@Jonas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240780/generate-a-name-vector-matlab/5240800#5240800). SPRINTF will do the repeating for you avoiding the need for a mask:

```
>> n = 5;
>> out = sprintf('x%u,', 1:n);
>> out(end) = []

out =

x1,x2,x3,x4,x5
```

Answer (score 1):

The better answer is, don't do it. While you CAN do so, this will likely cause more heartache for you in the future than you want. Having hundreds of such variables floating around is silly, when you can use an array to index the same data. Thus perhaps x{1}, x{2}, ....